# Excel VBA: Runtime Error 1004 When Deleting Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still working on learning VBA, so this might be a dumb question, but I'm looking to loop through a workbook of ~ 90-95 sheets, break each out into its own workbook, and save it as the name of the worksheet from the original file.

The script works, but only if I comment out the .Worksheets(1).Delete, and I'm wondering why...It throws a 1004 error on both sheets that I'm running it against, but not in the same spot. The first sheet errors out on tab 4, the second on tab 40-something.

Right now I've got the FileNamePrefix variable set up to toggle, because I'm running this in the VBA window under "ThisWorkbook", since I haven't figured out how to run this macro from its own sheet, and choose the prefix based on the name/extension of the file it maps to. (AC comes to me as a .xlsm, CC as a .xlsx) That is still on my to-do, so no spoilers, please! :)

Macro:

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ActiveSheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileNamePrefix As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    'FileNamePrefix = "CC Dashboard "
    FileNamePrefix = "AC Dashboard "
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    MsgBox (" This will create: " & WS_Count & " Files")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        With wb
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Worksheets(1).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileNamePrefix & ws.Name
            .Close False
        End With
        ws.Name = FileNamePrefix & ws.Name
    Next
    MsgBox (" Done! ")
End Sub
```

Comment: *and save it as the name of the worksheet from the original file* The problem is that sheet's name can contain characters that are invalid for file system file names.

Comment: `.Worksheets(1).Delete` In your loop you eventually delete last sheet. There must be at least one sheet in workbook - that's why you get the error.

Comment: I think that was the issue, I was moving a hidden sheet over, and then deleting the default "sheet1", which caused the issue. I found out that there were hidden sheets by accident, and that brought a ton of things to light. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets get rid of the Delete and just create the new file with only the worksheet you want.  I also did a little clean up on your code.

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ActiveSheetName, FileNamePrefix, FileName, FilePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'FileNamePrefix = "CC Dashboard "
    FileNamePrefix = "AC Dashboard "
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    MsgBox (" This will create: " & WS_Count & " Files")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Copy 'this creates a new file with only the one sheet, so no Delete needed
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileNamePrefix & ws.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    MsgBox (" Done! ")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! (I hit enter too fast...) I actually took this and was working on modifying it to work with an export as well, there were some new requirements from the person requesting this from me, and they wanted them as PDFs, and I ran into the same issue, BUT, it turns out that it was because of some hidden sheets...Why does that cause an issue with a loop like this?

Comment: Because Excel requires that a workbook has at least 1 visible sheet and this code is trying to create a new workbook with only one hidden worksheet.  Add a check for "If ws.Visible then" at the start of the loop (don't forget the "End If) and that should handle the hidden worksheets.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you, again. I really appreciate the info.